# How to join different datasets using pyspark and then call a custom function which takes a pandas dataframe to convert into xml file

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to join different datasets (hadoop export files) using pyspark and then call a custom function which takes a pandas dataframe to convert into xml file

Following is what i am doing:

```
def get_schema(header,col_num,file_name):
    fields = [StructField(field_name,StringType(),True) for field_name in header]
    schema = StructType(fields)
    new_file = sc.textFile(file_name)
    temp = new_file.map(lambda k: k.split("\x01")).map(lambda p : [eval("p["+str(ent)+"]") for ent in col_num])
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(temp, schema)
    return df

pow_header = [a,b,c]
chan_header = [a,b,d,e,f]
df_pow = get_schema(pow_header,[0,1,3],"pow_sample")
df_chan = get_schema(chan_header,[0,3,5,6,7],"chan_sample")
df_pow.registerTempTable("power")
df_chan.registerTempTable("chan")
query = "select a,b,c,NULL as d,NULL as e, NULL as f from power p UNION ALL\
         select a,b,NULL as c, d,e,f from tune t"
result = sqlContext.sql(query)
test = result.sort(a,b).rdd
data = test.flatMap(lambda x: my_func(x,dt)).collect()
```

what i am trying to do here is with the data set i have joined i need to write out to xml file, but that is done using my custom function called my_func.

I am unable to do this and i get the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98,
>   in main
>       command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line
>   164, in _read_with_length
>       return self.loads(obj)   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line
>   422, in loads
>       return pickle.loads(obj) ImportError: No module named my_func
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     ... 1 more
> ```

Comment: where is `my_func` ?

Comment: @WoodChopper from func import my_func is my python class files which works perfectly when used in native python or even python interpretor. 

Also just for info i can write out csv using spark-csv but issue is the paritionby columnName  is not creating perfect partitions, so that i could write out csv's and read them in parallel in python